# Is there a way to only update changed values when using Hasura's `on_conflict` filters?

Tags: hasura

I saw that on the [Hasura documentation](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/mutations/postgres/upsert/#update-selected-columns-on-conflict-using-a-filter) you can transform an insert conflict into an update statement (upsert) by using the `on_conflict` property.

This works well but in our case, we send an array of objects (which are equivalent to a table row) in the GraphQL query, and I would only like to do the update if a certain object attribute has changed. Here is an example of what we would like to do (the syntax is made up):

```json
on_conflict: {
  constraint: degrees_key,
    update_columns: [completion_year],
      where: {
        completion_year: { _neq: submitted_completion_year }
  }
}
```

So in this example, you would have a table with a degree where you would only update the completion year. We would only allow updates on this column using permissions. Right now the way we achieve this is by filtering existing rows before we do the inserts.

By being able to check if the `completion_year` is not the same, we could let the server do the filtering. Meaning we send all the rows to Hasura and if the field `completion_year` is the same, then we would ignore that row. It would actually be better to do this verification server side than client side.

Is there a way to do this? I could not find any example where the filter clause would refer back to the values being in conflict.

Comment: Hi friend, Hasura basically follows how Postgres does Upserts, is there an example of what you're trying to accomplish in SQL?

Comment: @ArjunYelamanchili I just updated the question with more details. I hope this helps!

Comment: I don't think theres currently a way to do this on the Hasura side right now to answer your original question. If you were just using Postgres, with no Hasura, how would you do it?

Comment: @ArjunYelamanchili I guess you could possibly be doing a subselect to filter out preexisting data? I'm not too sure how Hasura works if it's using the `where` clause to do subselects or if it just catches errors after trying to do the inserts